# How to set fixed column width in react-admin List - Datagrid?

Tags: list, datagrid, react-admin

I have used makeStyles to change TextField padding within a column, which increases the column, for example but cannot figure out how to set fixed width for the column. It always auto-sizes it whatever I try. I want to make it narrower (id column) because it has too much empty space to the right.